# Set window to non-resizable in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

How? :SS Or is that possible at all? :S

Comment: You will need to be a lot clearer with your question.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but you may want to clarify on whether you are resizing a Flex or AIR application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to fix the width of the swf?

The answer is Yes

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```